# How to handle nulls in LINQ when using Min or Max?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, null

I have the following Linq query:

```
result.Partials.Where(o => o.IsPositive).Min(o => o.Result)
```

I get an exception when `result.Partials.Where(o => o.IsPositive)` does not contains elements. Is there an elegant way to handle this other than splitting the operation in two and checking for null? I have a class full of operations like this one.

EDIT: The question is related with LINQ to Objects.

This is the Exception I'm getting (translated it says: The sequence is empty):

[image]

Comment: What exception do you get? In my experience, if `Partials` is empty, you should get 0.

Comment: your stack trace has a call to `Min()` not `Sum()`.  What is `result`?

Comment: Sorry. My bad, the operation is Min and Max not Sum. Sorry again. Editing the question.

Comment: Are you sure that line is what's throwing the exception? The exception is thrown by the `Min()` method, not `Where()` or `Sum()`.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

### A short summary of the calculation of a `Min`

#### - No mediation (Exception!)

```
   var min = result.Partials.Where(o => o.IsPositive).Min(o => o.Result);
```

This is your case: if there are no matching elements, then the `Min` call will raise an exception (`InvalidOperationException`).

#### - With `DefaultIfEmpty()` -- still troublesome

```
 var min = result.Partials.Where(o => o.IsPositive)
                          .Select(o => o.Result)
                          .DefaultIfEmpty()
                          .Min();
```

`DefaultIfEmpty` will create an enumeration over the 0 element, when there are no elements in the list. How do you know that 0 is the `Min` or if 0 stands for a list with no elements?

#### - Nullable values; A better solution

```
   var min = result.Partials.Where(o => o.IsPositive)
                            .Min(o => (decimal?)o.Result);
```

Here `Min` is either null (because that's equal to `default(decimal?)`) or the actual `Min` found.

So a consumer of this result will know that:

1. When result is `null` then the list *had no elements*
2. When the result is a decimal value then the list *had some elements* and the `Min` of those elements is that returned value.

However, when this doesn't matter, then `min.GetValueOrDefault(0)` can be called.

Comment: I'd like to add the following: if your property is nullable and the source collection can contain `null` values, getting a `null` result can mean two things: either the collection had no elements, or all values for the given property were `null`.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `DefaultIfEmpty` method to ensure the collection has at least 1 item:

```
result.Partials.Where(o => o.IsPositive).Select(o => o.Result).DefaultIfEmpty().Min();
```

Comment: ..what if the default value is null?

Comment: @RitchMelton: I believe Min will return null.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that calling `o.Result` with a null element causes an exception to be thrown.

Comment: @Ritch: Yes, of course. I was reading the documentation for `decimal?`, instead of the generic case. Will update answer.

Comment: too clumsy. i use same method as Adrian Iftode suggested - cast selected field as nullable

Answer (score 7):

You can't use `Min` (or `Max`) if the sequence is empty.  If that shouldn't be happening, you have a different issue with how you define `result`.  Otherwise, you should check if the sequence is empty and handle appropriately, eg:

```
var query = result.Partials.Where(o => o.IsPositve);
min = query.Any() ? query.Min(o => o.Result) : 0; // insert a different "default" value of your choice...
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to express it in LINQ is to use [Aggregate](http://www.csharp-examples.net/linq-aggregate/):

```
var min = result.Partials
    .Where(o => o.IsPositive)
    .Select(o => o.Result)
    .Aggregate(0, Math.Min); // Or any other value which should be returned for empty list
```

Answer (score 1):

Since LINQ lacks methods like `MinOrDefault()` and `MaxOrDefault()`, you can create them by yourself:

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static TProp MinOrDefault<TItem, TProp>(this IEnumerable<TItem> This, Func<TItem, TProp> selector)
    {
        if (This.Count() > 0)
        {
            return This.Min(selector);
        }
        else
        {
            return default(TProp);
        }
    }
}
```

Therefore, if the collection has values, the `Min()` is calculated, otherwise you get the property type's default value.

An example of use:

```
public class Model
{
    public int Result { get; set; }
}

// ...

public void SomeMethod()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    var filledList = new List<Model>
    {
        new Model { Result = 10 },
        new Model { Result = 9 },
    };
    var emptyList = new List<Model>();
    var minFromFilledList = filledList.MinOrDefault(o => o.Result)); // 9
    var minFromEmptyList = emptyList.MinOrDefault(o => o.Result)); // 0
}
```

**NOTE 1**: you don't need to check if the `This` parameter is null: the invoked `Count()` already checks that, and it throws the same Exception that you would throw.

**NOTE 2**: This solution is good only in situations where the `Count()` method is cheap to call. All .NET collections are fine since they are all very efficient; it could be a problem for particular customized/non-standard collections.