# Min vs max in linq.

Tags: linq

Please help me understand why second line returns exception if  my runs are empty.
I can take maxDate even if some of my schedules haven't runs

```
var maxDate = schedulingList.Max(p => p.Runs.Max(x => x.StartDate));
var minDate = schedulingList.Min(s => s.Runs.Min(r => r.StartDate));
```

what is the best way to get minDate ( null is posible ) ?
Great thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle nulls in LINQ when using Min or Max?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852599/how-to-handle-nulls-in-linq-when-using-min-or-max)

Answer (score 0):

You can select all your dates, do a DefaultIfEmpty on it, then get the min and max.

`DefaultIfEmpty` method will ensure that you have at least 1 item https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360179(v=vs.110).aspx

```
var dates = schedulingList.SelectMany(p=>p.Runs.Select(t=>t.startDate)).DefaultIfEmpty();
var maxDate = dates.Max();
var minDate = dates.Min();
```

Answer (score -1):

var minDate = schedulingList.Min(s => s.Runs.Min(r => r.StartDate)).FirstorDefault();

Hope this work,